# Error : Heap block at X modified

Tags: c++, c++11, runtime-error, destructor

I was trying to use destructors for a struct. However, the compiler reported errors that `Heap block at 006651F8 modified at 00665229 past requested size of 29 gift1.exe has triggered a breakpoint.`

```
    #include "stdafx.h"

    struct Node{
        char *name;
        int age;

        Node(char *n = 0, int a = 0){
            this->name = _strdup(n);
            age = a;
        }

        ~Node(){
            if (this->name != 0)
                delete[] this->name;
        }
    };

    int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
    {

        Node node1("Andy", 20);
        return 0;
    }
```

May I know where went wrong?

Does it matter if I use `name`instead of `this->name` ?

**Add-on:**

Even if I change it to `free(this->name);` as suggested by the answers below, the same error appears. `Heap block at 00EA68D8 modified at 00EA6909 past requested size of 29 gift1.exe has triggered a breakpoint.`

Comment: _strdup is a C function (AFAIK) so it most likely used malloc, you cannot delete malloced memory (new -> delete, malloc -> free). You have to free it. But really you should be using std::string.

Comment: BTW `name` and `this->name` do the same

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`_strdup`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/y471khhc.aspx) uses `malloc()` internally:

> **The `_strdup` function calls `malloc`** to allocate storage space for a copy of strSource and then copies strSource to the allocated space.

but you are using [`delete[]`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/new/operator_delete) to deallocate:

> Deallocates storage previously allocated by a matching operator new... If the pointer passed to the standard library deallocation function was not obtained from the corresponding standard library allocation function, the behavior is undefined.

To solve, use `std::string` instead of a `char*`(or if you really cannot use `std::string` use `free()` and prevent copying or implement copying for `Node`).

Comment: I guess "prevent copying or implement copying" is a terse reference to [this](http://stackoverflow.com/q/4172722/509868)

Comment: Even if I change it to `free(this->name);`, the same error appears. `Heap block at 00EA68D8 modified at 00EA6909 past requested size of 29
gift1.exe has triggered a breakpoint.`

Comment: @lxjhk, are you certain you have rebuilt? To be sure, perform a clean and the rebuild.

Comment: @hmjd Yes, I have cleaned and rebuilt the solution but the problem persists. I am using MSV 2013.

Comment: @lxjhk, I just did that and no problems (with 2010 and 2013).

Comment: @lxjhk, can you post your compiler arguments?

Comment: @hmjd May I know how to view the compiler arguments? If I change the setting to `X64`, the program will execute without errors but once I switch to `Win32`, the problem appears.

Comment: If you using the IDE it should be displayed in the output window (I built both x64 and x86 and both worked correctly).

Answer (score 0):

If you check [the documentation for `_strdup` (aka `strdup`)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/y471khhc.aspx) you will see that it uses `malloc` internally to allocate the string, therefore the memory must be freed with a call to `free` instead of `delete`.